# Any pipeline resolves in Error: unknown command "sh" for "executor" Run 'executor --help' for usage

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

Right now I am trying to learn CI/CD on GitLab. Unfortunately, I cant make a simple pipeline run on my project. The runner doesn't seem to work somehow.
Here is an image of the project:
[image: File listing containing a bilder, .gitignore, .gitlab-ci.yml, and README.md]

I wrote this in my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"

test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```

which is just the original code from the GitLab Tutorial for creating a simple pipeline.

Unfortunately i get this error afterwards:

```
Using docker image sha256:7053f62a27a84985c6ac886fcb5f9fa74090edb46536486f69364e3360f7c9ad for gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug with digest gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:fcccd2ab9f3892e33fc7f2e950c8e4fc665e7a4c66f6a9d70b300d7a2103592f ...
Error: unknown command "sh" for "executor"
Run 'executor --help' for usage
```

I'm using the shared runners of GitLab for the pipelines.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: The question doesn't have enough information to be answerable without following links (and content in links doesn't count towards meeting [mre] requirements) -- but in general, `sh` is the default interpreter used to run shell commands; when you create a `script` block, each command will presumably run with `sh`.

Comment: The way to avoid needing that, in general, is instead of passing a command as a string to look at whether there's an interface that lets you pass an explicit argv; for example, if gitlab (which I don't know and can't speak to) will let you run `["/bin/echo", "This job tests something"]`, that's directly invoking `/bin/echo` without `/bin/sh` being involved, so `echo` is the only executable that needs to be present.

Comment: (And _please_ include the error **as text**, not a screenshot! See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122))

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted runner or the shared gitlab.com runners? I don't see anything in your job configuration that explains why the image `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor` is trying to be used. I suspect this is either a problem with the runner configuration and/or image being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job is trying to use the image `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor` -- but this image defines an `ENTRYPOINT` that points to the `/kaniko/executor` binary and is therefore not compatible to be used as a job image in GitLab CI. See [this answer for a full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266227/5747944) of why this is problematic. Basically gitlab is trying to send commands to the job container, but is unexpectedly calling the `executor` binary, which results in the error message which comes from `/kaniko/executor`

```
Error: unknown command "sh" for "executor"
Run 'executor --help' for usage
```

Because there's nothing in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration that would cause this image to be used, this is likely caused by the configuration of the runner you are using which specifies this as the default image when no `image:` key is present.

You can specify a different image to get around this problem:

```yaml
image: alpine  # as a global key default

build-job:
  stage: build
  image: alpine # or on a per-job basis
```

If you really want to use this particular image (you almost certainly do not), you'll need to override the entrypoint:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor
    entrypoint: [""]
```

If you manage the GitLab runner configuration, you should change the default `image` configuration to be a usable image.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me!
I tried using alpine as an image but now it says:
"ERROR: The "alpine" image is not present on list of allowed images:"
I enabled the shared runners in the settings and alpine is one of them. 
I certanly don't have another comfiguration as that. :(

The other option with kaniko as image doesnt work either. I get:
ERROR: The "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor" image is not present on list of allowed images: 
- alpine:*

Comment: @Teamy it looks like the administrator who manages your runner has not configured it correctly and has some limitation on what images you're allowed to use. Your best bet is to reach out to your GitLab administrator. You won't have this problem, for example, if you start an account on gitlab.com and try the same thing with gitlab.com shared runners.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug`

It works fine for me:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/joel.winarske/docker-containers/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml#L2