# The same docker image and yaml file on two computers gitlabs execute differenctly

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to generate doxygen documentation using GitLab CI/CD.

On my Ubuntu computer it works fine, but on my server (running on Ubuntu as well it does not)

On my computer:

```
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/Piotr/doxygen-test/.git/
Checking out cd74c1b2 as detached HEAD (ref is DOXYGEN-MASTER)...
Removing warn.log
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:06
Using docker image sha256:e6199347aa9ac5396eb43c2f808da322206fb532a7523d55710f2e4b6d23b27a for gul-doxygen-noentry:latest ...
$ echo "executing the doxygen"
executing the doxygen
$ doxygen ./Doxyfile
```

On the server:

```
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on runner-a-9fmufr-project-79-concurrent-0 via srvlnx01...
Getting source from Git repository 00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/Piotr/doxygen-test/.git/
Checking out 5ca96c41 as detached HEAD (ref is DOXYGEN-MASTER)...
Removing Dockerfile
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:02
Using docker image sha256:02b28832c626ab59f98b137ac9a5a417888c6fdb997ec845a208f855493c9d9a for gul-doxygen:latest ...
error: configuration file sh not found!
```

And it is running doxygen without parameters.

On both .yaml file is the same.

```
image: 
  name: gul-doxygen:latest
  entrypoint: [""]


pages:
  script:
    - echo "executing the doxygen"
    - doxygen ./Doxyfile
    - ls -l ../documentation
    - mv ../documentation/html/ public/  
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - DOXYGEN-MASTER
```

Why does it behave differently on two computers?

Comment: Where does the image `gul-doxygen` come from? It's not on docker hub.

Comment: @larsks it is local one

Comment: @larsks I do not know what this strange error means. `error: configuration file sh not found!` it does not even echo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configuration file sh not found` error happens because your image defines an `ENTRYPOINT`, which is [incompatible with running in GitLab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266227/5747944) without overriding the entrypoint in the `image:entrypoint:` configuration. This behavior is different between the two images `gul-doxygen-noentry:latest` and `gul-doxygen:latest` because the images are genuinely different in this regard.

You are overriding your entrypoint in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration with `image:entrypoint:`, however, if you're still experiencing this issue, it's because the runner is configured to disallow entrypoint overrides with the [`disable_entrypoint_overwrite` setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section).